# shared preferences from new boston tutorial button not working on click

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i have searched on SO but not found solution to my problem.
i m new to android and following new boston tutorial.
and in sharedpreferences activity buttons are not working on click.showing nothing no exception nothing
my code is :

```
package com.ss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SharedPrefs extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView sharedData;
    EditText showResults;
    SharedPreferences somedata;
    public static String filename = "MySharedString";

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.bSave:

                String stringData = showResults.getText().toString();
                Editor editor = somedata.edit(); // Editor from //
                                                    // sharedpreferecnes
                editor.putString("ourString", stringData);
                editor.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.bLoad:

                if (somedata.contains("ourString")) {
                    // getting data
                    String get = somedata.getString("ourString", null);

                    showResults.setText(get);
                }
                break;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sharedpreferences);

            setupVariables();
            somedata = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public void setupVariables() {
        try {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);
            Button load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLoad);
            sharedData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLoad);
            showResults = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvShowresults);

            save.setOnClickListener(this);
            load.setOnClickListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etShowresults"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLoad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLoad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load Your Data" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: somedata = getSharedPreferences(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //use this line in your oncreate view and replace from your load button click listener. It should be declared once in one activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the exception catching, this does nothing for you other than hide what's going on. You create Dialogs without ever showing any.

Also post your layout, I expect, purely by your variable naming convention, that `R.id.tvLoad` is a `TextView`, and you're trying to assign it to an `EditText`

If that's the case, make `R.id.tvLoad` an `EditText` in your layout.

Comment: yeah u caught it right..i have imprved that but the problm is still the same i have posted my code see.

Comment: You're still not showing the layout, and please please pretty please remove the exception handling, it doesn't help.

Comment: OK, one more time, remove the "entire" exception handling, try, catch, the whole lot, it's hiding some issue. Once you have done that, run your app again, then post the stacktrace.

Comment: Because it it hiding an issue! And I just see now, you have not updated the id in `showResults = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvShowresults);`

Comment: One last time, remove the try/catch, run the app, print the stacktrace.

Comment: i have not updated the code...here but i have done..anyways thanks yr:) i try somthing else.

Answer (score 0):

Make sharedprefernce like this ;

```
SharedPrefrences preferences = getSharedPreferences(key_value,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
 //Now put values in editor 
editor.putString(key_value_for_access ,string_value_to_store );
editor.commit();
//Now for accessing this into every activity you have to write the same thing:

    SharedPrefrences preferences = getSharedPreferences(key_value,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(prefernces.contains(key_value_for_access)){
    //getting data
    String get = preferences.getString(key_value_for_access, null);
    }
```

Comment: not working.when i press save button and load button it does not work